# Adding multiple parameters of the same name - apiary

Tags: apiblueprint

Am I able to specify multiple query parameters with the same name? In the example below, I wish to register a domain with two different name servers.

"## Register a domain [/domain/register{?domainname,nameserver,nameserver}]

- Parameters

  - domainname: test.com - The domain name you wish to register
  - nameserver: - First nameserver to use
  - nameserver: - Second nameserver to use 
    "

I hope you can help!

Thanks guys,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not yet, but in your case having `ns1` and `ns2` should suffice. Or do you really need to have the same parameter name?